# how to use to latex read all content of a file concluding some lines have "%"

Tags: latex

I am new in latex,and when I use pdflatex to read files,I found that some lines(that has "%") cannot be read,how can I bypass this?
this is my .tex file

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newread\file
\openin\file=test.txt
\newwrite\fileo
\immediate\openout\fileo=ss.txt
\loop\unless\ifeof\file
\read\file to\fileline 
\immediate\write\fileo{\fileline}   
\repeat
\closeout\fileo
\closein\file
sometext(not important)
\end{document}
```

and this is test.txt

```
%abcdefg
aaa
sss
```

after pdflatex the .tex file,the results would be

```
aaa
sss
```

how can I get the firstline:"%abcdefg"

Answer (score 1):

You have to scape the character. Some characters have special meanings in LaTeX:

`&` `%` `#` `_` `~` `^` `\` `{` `}` `$`

To scape most of them, just add `\` and others have their own command:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}

    \& \% \# \_ \$ \{ \} \textasciitilde \textasciicircum \textbackslash

    % A comment line
    % In your code should be:

    \%abcdefg \\
    aaa \\
    sss

\end{document}
```

As you can see, if you don't scape the % character, it would comment out a line of text in your source code. I hope i have helped

Edit: As you said you can't change the test.txt file you can do it deactivating % as a special character adding `` \catcode`\%=12 `` after `\begin{document}`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \catcode`\%=12
    \newread\file
    \openin\file=test.txt
    \newwrite\fileo
    \immediate\openout\fileo=ss.txt
    \loop\unless\ifeof\file
    \read\file to\fileline 
    \immediate\write\fileo{\fileline}   
    \repeat
    \closeout\fileo
    \closein\file
    sometext(not important)
\end{document}
```

Comment: but  the .text file can not  be changed ,so I have to do sth in the .tex file to solve this

Comment: Just add ```\catcode`\%=12 ```. I edited the answer.